# All independent variables are categorical and dependent(target) variable is continuous

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, data-science, categorical-data

This is the data I need to build model upon:

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f396t.jpg)

- dataframe contains 834 rows and 4 columns('Size','Sector','Road Connectivity','Price')
- AIM is to train a model so as to predict the price
- 'Size','Sector' and 'Road connectivity' are 3 features which are assigned to X variable.
- 'Price' i.e our target feature is assigned to y variable
- i have made a pipeline which consists of one hot encoder and linear regressor
  below is the code:

```
ohc=OneHotEncoder(categories = "auto")
lr=LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True,normalize=True)
pipe=make_pipeline(ohc,lr)
```

```
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
kfolds=ShuffleSplit(n_splits=5,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
cross_val_score(pipe,X,y,cv=kfolds).mean()
```

output =0.8970496076598085

```
xinp=([['04M','Sec 10','C road']])
pipe.fit(X,y)
pipe.predict(xinp)
```

now when I pass the values to pipeline to predict it shows an error:

"""Found unknown categories ['Sec 10'] in column 1 during transform"""

ANY SUGGESTIONS which help build the model are appreciated...

Comment: Try catboost regressor - https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/python-usages-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you provided category (in `xinp`, the `Sec 10` value), that was not present in training data, thus it can not be one hot encoded, because there is no dummy variable (no corresponding binary column) for it. One of possible solutions can be following:

```
ohc=OneHotEncoder(categories = "auto", handle_unknown = "ignore")
```

From scikit one hot encoder [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html):

> **handle_unknown{‘error’, ‘ignore’}, default=’error’**
>
> Whether to raise an error or ignore if an unknown categorical feature is present during transform (default is to raise). When this
> parameter is set to ‘ignore’ and an unknown category is encountered
> during transform, the resulting one-hot encoded columns for this
> feature will be all zeros. In the inverse transform, an unknown
> category will be denoted as None.

Comment: already tried , it just ignores the error and then predicts the wrong value, even changing the category to another one ,it still predicts wrong value or raises error. the model is unable to fit "Sector" feature i think

Comment: It wont be able to predict the value correctly, just because of the logic behind the model: It never saw the category "Sec 10" during the training, so it can not tell anything about it and it's relation to price. You would need to have some dataset samples where "Sector" variable is "Sec 10" so the model will be able to learn some relation between it and price.

Comment: even if i change the category , the result is same , even if i take training data values , result is same i.e. either it shows error and if errors are set to be ignored , predicted value is way smaller or larger than the actual value. what you are trying to make me understand , i have already tried it and i think the problem is either with the encoder or with regressor or the training data is not large enough to build model on it .I just don't know what the problem is!!!!!

Comment: From the screenshot of your dataframe, it can not be told number of rows in your dataset (only first 5 rows can be seen). Can you please provide full dataset (not just screenshot), so that problem is reproducible?

Comment: the data is of a client and i can't share it on public platform but i can show it you in private message . Do leave your contact in comment. thank you